# displaying arabic character with JSON

Tags: json, unicode, utf-8, arabic

i'm trying to create an arabic json file using php, but the problem is that i'm getting weird characters instead of the usual arabic letters (Ø§Ø¨Ùˆ Ù…ÙŠØ²Ø§Ù†).

i'm using 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

i have tried to find a solution to the problem but i'm stuck
i have tested to output the string on a php file and it is working, and arabic letters are displaying, and the json string is as i want it.

but whenever i put the json header, header('Content-type: application/json');
i'm getting the weird characters

can anyone help
could this be related to my php (5.1.6) version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set header in this way:-

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
```